# Installing Ruby on Rails on windows 7 and starting web development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have already seen some tutorial for ruby on rails programming.I am new with ruby programming.I am quite good with PHP programming and PHP frameworks.But i don't know how to start ruby on rails programming.And i am facing some problems for installing ruby on rails on my windows 7 operating system.
It will be nice if someone helps me for installing and starting how to development.

Comment: do not do that to yourself... Get any Linux distribution installed along your Windows in 20 minutes and get rid of hours and hours of future pain dealing with Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://railsinstaller.com will be your best friend here!

There's also a [great resource here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/310-getting-started-with-rails):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby/installer.

I teach ROR at Community College, and my students experimented with both Railsinstaller, and Bitnami. We had fewer issues (actually none) with the Bitnami installer. In addition, Bitnami installs both MySQL and Postgres as part of the install. We used the 1.9.3/Rails 3 stack, so I can only speak for that. It was flawless on both Windoes 7 & 8.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install following program in order to run and start working for Ruby on Rails:

1. Download Ruby https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
2. Download PostgreSQL (database) https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
3. On CMD commend please write: gem install Rails  (then enter it will download all dependency)
4. Download Visual Studio Code : https://code.visualstudio.com/download
5. Git base download : https://git-scm.com/download/win